# How to remove non breaking space from body/value in migration process?

Tags: migrations, plugins

I am successfully migrating the content from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9. However, I am getting some extra non-breaking spaces I'd like to remove.

> [image: screenshot]

I tried using a basic *str_replace* plugin, but that doesn't work.

> [image: screenshot]

What am I doing wrong? What else should I look into?

Comment: Have you confirmed that string exists in the source data?

Answer (score 2):

By taking a look into the [StrReplace class](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/migrate_plus/-/blob/8.x-5.x/src/Plugin/migrate/process/StrReplace.php) I see that you are missing the source key, which should be the name of the field/column/whatever you are importing from.

If it does not work, try to also remove the "regex" key and if it still does not, try to use a simpler search, to ensure that the problem does not lie with your data.